# How to define multidimensional dictionary with default value in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, autovivification

I would like to modify next dict definition:

```
class Vividict(dict):
      def __missing__(self, key):
           value = self[key] = type(self)()
           return value
```

To be able to use it in next way:

```
totals[year][month] += amount
```

Comment: have you looked at collections.defaultdict?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

d = defaultdict(Counter)
d['year']['month'] += 1
```

Comment: d[year][month][day] += 1

Comment: @buslik that cannot work, because if you do `d['year']['month'] += 1` with whatever structure `d` is, you setting values of `d['year']['month']` to `int` objects.

Comment: By d = defaultdict(Counter) we are creating two dimensional dict. One dimension come from  defaultdict another from Counter.

Comment: @buslik you absolutely right. But, as i already said, there is no way that you can achieve that. You should choose between `dict` and `int`.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I have used Counter with tuple as a key.